# CRM - Schedule Service Activity - Error retrieving availability

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013, subgrid

I am searching for availability of a resource and getting a not particularly helpful error. The subgrid fails to refresh.
This is OOTB functionality with no custom actions

Any Ideas?

Schedule Service Activity
Select the customers, service, and resources for this activity.
Select the date, time, and duration, and click Find Available Times.
Select the time you want from the list of available times, and click Schedule

[image: Schedule Service Planner]

**POST:**

```
GridControl.js?ver=-821682931:1 POST https://****.****/****/AppWebServices/AppGridWebService.ashx?operation=Refresh 500 (Internal Server Error)
execute @ VM66800 global.ashx?ver=-821682931:7
executeInternal @ GridControl.js?ver=-821682931:1
$5f_3 @ GridControl.js?ver=-821682931:1
$4T_3 @ GridControl.js?ver=-821682931:1
set_pageNumber @ GridControl.js?ver=-821682931:1
Search @ schedulingdialog.js?ver=-821682931:1
onclick @ schedulingdialog.aspx?ActivityId=&ActivityTypeCode=4214&dType=1:380
```

**Unhandled Exception:**

```
System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[[Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.OrganizationServiceFault, Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]]: System.Xml.XmlException: Microsoft Dynamics CRM has experienced an error. Reference number for administrators or support: #59FB87F1Detail: <OrganizationServiceFault xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts"> <ErrorCode>-2147220970</ErrorCode> <ErrorDetails xmlns:d2p1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Collections.Generic" /> <Message>System.Xml.XmlException: Microsoft Dynamics CRM has experienced an error. Reference number for administrators or support: #59FB87F1</Message> <Timestamp>2018-01-09T12:24:52.7024342Z</Timestamp> <InnerFault> <ErrorCode>-2147220970</ErrorCode> <ErrorDetails xmlns:d3p1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Collections.Generic" /> <Message>System.NullReferenceException: Microsoft Dynamics CRM has experienced an error. Reference number for administrators or support: #E9DAA4DE</Message> <Timestamp>2018-01-09T12:24:52.7024342Z</Timestamp> <InnerFault i:nil="true" /> <TraceText i:nil="true" /> </InnerFault> <TraceText i:nil="true" /> </OrganizationServiceFault> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. at Microsoft.Crm.Core.Application.WebServices.AppGridWebServiceHandler.GetGridDataProvider(String gridXml) at Microsoft.Crm.Core.Application.WebServices.AppGridWebServiceHandler.Refresh(String gridXml, StringBuilder sbXml, StringBuilder sbHtml, Boolean returnJsonData) at Microsoft.Crm.Core.Application.WebServices.AppGridWebServiceHandler.ProcessRequestInternal(HttpContext context) Not available Not available
Details
Not available
https://**.**/***/AppWebServices/AppGridWebService.ashx?operation=Refresh /***/AppWebServices/AppGridWebService.ashx?operation=Refresh ASHX_XML
```

Comment: In “start time” try to choose “Range of time” instead of “Anytime” & can you see the response?

Comment: Hi Arun, Yes i have tried Anytime with the same error

Comment: Not anytime. Something else. Also check the resource work week configuration.

Comment: I have checked all the options. Also i have set it all up exactly the same in a UAT environment & it returns the availability as expected. It seems specific to the DEV area, any ideas what might cause a problem like this?

Comment: Could be anything, did you try to see in browser dev toolbar console errors, crm platform trace or event viewer?